# Sensors : How to display the temperature in Fahrenheit?

Tags: debian, terminal, sensors

So after installing `lm-sensors` and `hddtemp` , I run `sensors` in the command line in linux, when it displays the temperatures it does it in Celsius, how can I make it display the temperature in Fahrenheit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# sensors -f
```

should do it according to [`man sensors`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sensors):

> -f
>
> Print the temperatures in degrees Fahrenheit instead of Celsius.

Comment: Why voting down, it is the right answer ?

Comment: I didn't mean to vote it down, I went to hit the check mark and my cat jarred my arm. I corrected the mistake.